# Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I'm using Appium for iOS Automation testing and I'm getting this error

Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement //*[@text='Search Results']

Appium Java client version: 6.0.0-BETA5

Downgrading java client is not an option for me as I'm using some methods from the latest beta version.

```
try {
        MobileElement titleView = navigationBar.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='" + title + "']"));
        return titleView.isDisplayed();
    }
```

UPDATE:

I added selenium in my gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'io.appium:java-client:6.0.0-BETA5'
implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.9.1'

implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

But when running tests, I still get the error. The build version here is 3.11.0. Is that Selenium? What is the right approach here?

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: //*[@text='Search Results']
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'USGPSNYCM212943.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:462:ed8d:f2e4:f85d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi Please use following dependencies :

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-BETA5</version>
        </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This should solve your problem, even i faced similar issue when i used different selenium server version.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do this in gradle? I'm very new to this

Comment: Updated my question above, please lmk what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi @Suraj, I am also facing the same issue I have used above mentioned dependencies:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        
        But getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue for a couple of days. I tried all the solutions mentioned on various forums like upgrading or downgrading the appium version etc. Finally, the issue was resolved by adding a simple implicit wait of 5 seconds on the driver object. Give it a try if you are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is seeing this now, then WebElement search depends upon the what driver you are using.

If AndroidDriver is used then refer generic type as 
AndroidDriver driver;
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

If appiumDriver is used then refer generic type as 
AppiumDriver driver;
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the Desired Capabilities add the following additional Capabilities, it should work then:

```
capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
Appium-windows-1.13.0
java-client-5.0.0-BETA6
```

I have updated it to

```
Appium-windows-1.15.1
java-client-6.0.0-BETA4
```

and it worked